# Printing positions in field for same numbers, c language

Tags: c

we got a homework in school to make this type of programme I share here. I have it done its working but I need this: If I put 2 or more same lowest or highest numbers I need to print position of all same lowest and highest numbers. And I am stucked here. Can you help me, Thanks

code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int pole[100];
int i, max_cislo, min_cislo, x, max, min;

printf("Napis, kolko cisel chces ulozit do pola :");
scanf("%d",&x);
   
printf("Vloz %d cisla do pola :\n",x);
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    
        printf("cislo %d -: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&pole[i]);
    }
max_cislo = pole[0];
min_cislo = pole[0];

for(i=1; i<x; i++){
    
        if(pole[i]>max_cislo){
            
            max_cislo = pole[i];
            max = i;
        }


        if(pole[i]<min_cislo){
            
            min_cislo = pole[i];
            min = i;
        }
    }
printf("Maximalny prvok je : %d a jeho pozicia v poli je: %d\n", max_cislo, max);
printf("Minimalny prvok je : %d a jeho pozicia v poli je: %d\n", min_cislo, min);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

- Allocate an array to store all min/max positions.
- Remove all elements and store new position if the record is breaked.
- Add new position to the list if the record is tie.

It will be like this (only max is shown, min can also be done like this):

```
int pole[100], x;
int i, max_poses[100], max_pos_count = 0, max = 0;

/* read things to pole and x */

max = pole[0];
max_poses[0] = 0;
max_pos_count = 1;
for (i = 1; i < x; i++) {
    if (pole[i] > max) {
        /* the record is broken */
        max = pole[i];
        max_poses[0] = i;
        max_pos_count = 1;
    } else if (pole[i] == max) {
        /* tie */
        max_poses[max_pos_count++] = i;
    }
}
```